# how to construct minimum mean squared error estimator from a sample data? and show that it is unbiased?

Tags: mean-square-error

Given the following sample of data:
 3,6,13,27,9,14,8,6

a) Construct a minimum MSE estimator.
b) Show that it is unbiased.
c) Use the estimator to predict a 9th observation

Comment: What have your tried?

Comment: I have tried calculating expectation for part a. Not sure if that's the right way to go about it.